# How to add map to static cell programmatically?

Tags: swift

I have a section in the table view, one of the section cell shows the map.

I know how to add map with IB, but I want to add it to static cell programmatically.

Comment: Are you using google maps or apple maps?

Comment: There are many tutorials available which show how to add map without IB. Please make some search effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-

```
let mapView = MKMapView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
if let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "resuseIdentifier") {
  tablecell = cell
} else {
    tablecell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "resuseIdentifier")
}
tablecell?.contentView.addSubview(mapView)
```

Comment: but how to specify which cell to use?

Comment: You can define the identifier